# Is it possible to get the origin of lines on a diff3 merge conflict or a composite diff in libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

I know how to generate a file containing the diff3: just copy the [following diff3 test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/3a495c19bd280f5455047a9ac0e936f2c2f2f9a9/tests/merge/workdir/simple.c#L259).

Suppose the diff3 would contain:

```
context1
<<<<<<< master
ours
||||||| base
base
=======
theirs
>>>>>>> topic
context2
```

What I want it to get the following map:

```
line        origin
-------------------
context1 -> CONTEXT
ours     -> OURS
base     -> BASE
theirs   -> THEIRS
context2 -> CONTEXT
```

possibly in a callback loop like is done for diff lines on [git_diff_print](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/diff/git_diff_print), which passes a `git_diff_line` to the callback, which contains the `origin` attribute [with values like `GIT_DIFF_LINE_CONTEXT`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/diff.h#L451)

Of course, I could parse the file and look for the conflict markers `<<<`, but that would lead to ambiguity if the file itself contained the markers, so I don't want to do that.

Alternatively, if I could get a composite diff (the default diff format during merge conflict resolution) as:

```
  context1
++<<<<<<< master
 +ours
++||||||| base
++base
++=======
+ theirs
++>>>>>>> topic
  context2
```

that would also be a possible solution, as there can be no ambiguity in this format because of the `+` and space characters. This would however be less good since I would still to do some manual parsing on stuff for which libgit2 already has the parsed information which it used to make the file in the first place.

I want to do this because I am implementing a merge resolution tool for GitLab: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7345

**Edit**

Since this seems not to be possible, I have made a proposal with an interface at: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, libgit2 does not provide an arbitrary three-way diff/merge tool that you can consume: although it *uses* a diff/merge tool internally to merge files, it does not provide callers a way to get hunk-by-hunk information about the merged data.

Instead, you should use any diff/merge tool of your choice.  (git and libgit2 use the [xdiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html) library, though you can use any library you wish.)

It's very easy to get the conflict data out of the index for some file named `filename` in a repository `repo` - then you can feed it to your tool:

```
git_index *index;
git_odb *odb;
git_index_entry *ancestor, *ours, *theirs;
git_odb_object *ancestor_file = NULL, *ours_file = NULL, *theirs_file = NULL;
const void *ancestor_data = NULL, *ours_data = NULL, *theirs_data = NULL;
size_t ancestor_size = 0, ours_size = 0, theirs_size = 0;

git_repository_index(&index, repo);
git_repository_odb(&odb, repo);

ancestor = git_index_get_bypath(index, filename, 1);
ours = git_index_get_bypath(index, filename, 2);
theirs = git_index_get_bypath(index, filename, 3);

if (ancestor) {
  git_odb_read(&ancestor_file, odb, &ancestor->id);

  ancestor_data = git_odb_object_data(ancestor_file);
  ancestor_size = git_odb_object_size(ancestor_file);
}

if (ours) {
  git_odb_read(&ours_file, odb, &ours->id);

  ours_data = git_odb_object_data(ours_file);
  ours_size = git_odb_object_size(ours_file);
}

if (theirs) {
  git_odb_read(&theirs_file, odb, &theirs->id);

  theirs_data = git_odb_object_data(theirs_file);
  theirs_size = git_odb_object_size(theirs_file);
}

/*
 * At this point, you can feed `ancestor_data`, `ours_data` and
 * `theirs_data` in to your diff/merge tool.  They are byte arrays
 * containing the contents of the file and are `ancestor_size`,
 * `ours_size` and `theirs_size` bytes long, respectively.
 *
 * If one any was `NULL`, then the conflict does not include
 * that side of the file, in the case of an add/add conflict or
 * if one side was deleted.
 */

git_odb_object_free(ancestor_file);
git_odb_object_free(ours_file);
git_odb_object_free(theirs_file);
```

(Note that this code is untested, and please note the lack of error checking.)

Comment: Thanks, Edward. Do you think this this something that libgit2 would consider a pull request for, or is it out of scope? I feel it is very close to the functionality exposed by diff3 / diff_print, and it is implemented by git. Otherwise I think I'll just parse git compound diff output on Grit.

Comment: @CiroSantilli I don't know - I would ask the other libgit2 contributors at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues

Comment: I have made a proposal with an interface prototype at: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2568